# NSNotificationCenter called twice in applicationDidEnterBackground when their is two view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using the the `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName` function with the `applicationDidEnterBackground` function. So first I add these to `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    println("applicationDidEnterBackground")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("com.test.mytest", object: self)
}
```

And I add these to `ViewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "myTestFunc", name: "com.test.mytest", object: nil)
}

func myTestFunc () {
    println("CALLED")
}
```

And up to now, everything is working fine, the console print out the right thing when I enter background:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
CALLED
```

But after I add a new view controller in Storyboard and connect both of them using any of Segue:

[image: storyboard]

[image: storyboard]

And now when I run the app, after I clicked two buttons and then back to the home page, the applicationDidEnterBackground is still calling once but the NSNotificationCenter is called twice:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
CALLED
CALLED
```

So how can I solve this weird problem?

EDIT

I've also tried this, but still same result:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "com.test.mytest", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "myTestFunc", name: "com.test.mytest", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: You could also listen to the system notification for this: [UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I forget the viewDidLoad is loaded twice... I solved by:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "com.test.mytest", object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. In my case solution was enabling `Background Modes` in project capabilities tab.